# Laravel Re-Indexing Primary Key Column Values & Reset AUTO_INCREMENT Value

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-9

Laravel eloquent has any method to re-indexing the primary keys values & update the next AUTO_INCREMENT value.

I've tried with the below query which update the primary key values as well as the AUTO_INCREMENT

**Re-Indexing**
`SET @newid=0; UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET id=(@newid:=@newid+1) ORDER BY id;`

**AUTO_INCREMENT**
`SET @newAutoIncrementValue = 0; SELECT @newAutoIncrementValue := max(id)+1 FROM TABLE_NAME; ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME AUTO_INCREMENT = @newAutoIncrementValue;`

But Looking for laravel eloquent has any method for re-indexing & update AUTO_INCREMENT value

Comment: what was the issue with the above queries?

Comment: above query has no problem need to know achieve this with any laravel eloquent method